# Am I allowed to use the Nexus kiosks if I am bringing wine with me?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canadian-citizens, nexus

Many years ago when I got my Nexus card, I was told I couldn't use it when I had anything that needed to be declared, such as food. To this day, when I travel from my home in Canada to the US, I make sure I don't have a granola bar in my carry-on or anything like that. This is sort of backed up by this statement on [the CBSA site](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/prog/nexus/air-aerien-eng.html):

> If you have any goods that are considered to be [restricted, controlled or prohibited](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/rpg-mrp-eng.html), or if the goods you are importing require a permit, such as firearms, you may not use the NEXUS line.

If you follow their link, Food is one of the bullets on the list. Wine and alcohol are not. I know from [the CBP site](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/190/~/bringing-alcohol-(including-homemade-wine)-to-the-u.s.-for-personal-use) that I can bring up to a litre in to the US. (Which kind of means it's restricted, no?, but it's not on that list.)

So, if I wrap up a 750ml bottle of wine in my checked luggage, wave goodbye to it at YYZ, then line up for preclearance in the Nexus lane, and use the kiosk, and answer truthfully to all the questions there, am I going to find myself sent all the way back to the end of the not-Nexus line to go through the talk-to-an-officer process? Am I risking losing my Nexus card by using the lane when I am bringing in something that should be declared? (And why don't any of these Nexus, CBSA, and CBP sites cover simple scenarios like this so that people can feel comfortable and confident crossing the border?)

Answer (score 2):

I've brought alcohol through NEXUS (although by a land crossing) and never had a problem.  Just be sure to declare it.  (I believe the kiosks ask questions such as whether you are beyond your exemption.  You'll want to research exactly what you're exemption includes to know how to accurately answer the question.)

If in doubt, don't use NEXUS.  But I don't see an issue here.